# Too many widgets

Tags: widgets

Basic and default drag and drop sorting of widgets in the admin area is ok, as long as there is a small number of them. I am currently in the situation where it seems that I will have a few hundreds of widgets. (every page need to have 4 widgets and there are hundred of pages). So we are talking about 400 widgets.

This is impossible to handle, search or edit easily. Just imagine opening all of them to find what you are looking for.

So question is : is there a good way to work with many widgets?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

WordPress admin is not designed to scale. If you are managing some resource which is 100x more than the average site, you need to be prepared to either develop your own solution to admin it or learn to live with it.

In the case of widgets you should try the customizer or the accessibility mode of the widget screen (the link to it is hidden in the "screen options")

Comment: +1 for customizer. It is designed for just this type of administrative context. In fact, you can click around several pages and change widgets before saving, and ALL settings will persist on save. Customizer also makes it easier to find and see WHICH widgets and areas you update in real time.